# How to parse this XML configuration file

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following XML config file which I want to be able to parse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configuration Name="MyConfiguration" Class="ConfigClass" Description="This is the main configuration.">
    <ConfigItem Name="AString" Value="1" Type="String" Description="This is a string." />
    <ConfigItem Name="APath" Value="..\path" Type="Path" Description="This is a path." />
    <Configuration Name="AnEnclosedConfiguration" Class="AnEnclosedClass" Description="An enclosed configuration.">
        <ConfigItem Name="AnInteger" Value="6" Type="Int" Description="This is an integer value." />
        <Configuration Name="AnotherEnclosedConfiguration" Class="AnotherEnclosedClass" Description="Another enclosed configuration.">
            <ConfigItem Name="ARangedValue" Value="1.6" Type="Double" Min="0.1" Max="7.6" Description="This is a ranged value." />
        </Configuration>
    </Configuration>
</Configuration>
```

As you can see there are two different kinds of nodes:
1) "Configuration": Which contains a set of ConfigItems and can also contain other enclosed/nested "Configuration" nodes.
2) "ConfigItem": Which represents a variable and contains Attributes for its "Value" and "Type". Furthermore these can contain a different number of attributes as you can see for example in the "ARangedValue", which contains the additional attributes "Min" and "Max".

I would like to be able to parse this file in C# so that I can access the values given in the attributes as properties of a dynamically created data-structure with thMyConfigr respective name. E.g. to access the "Min" value in "ARangedValue" I would do something like:

```
double MinValue = MyConfiguration.AnEnclosedConfiguration.AnotherEnclosedConfiguration.ARangedValue.Min;
```

or

```
Path PathValue = MyConfiguration.APath.Value;
```

I am completely new to XML and still somewhat fresh to C#. I have found that there is an "ExpandoObject", which might allow me to do what I am proposing. However I will also have to somehow read the Value and its Type and then dynamically cast it to the correct type or instantiate the correct type.

I have tried to create a set of serializable classes to recreate the XML structure shown above:

```
public class ConfigurationClass : List<ConfigItemBase>
{
    [XmlElement]
    public List<ConfigItemBase> ConfigItem
    {
        get { return configItem; }
        set { configItem = value; }
    }
    private List<ConfigItemBase> configItem;
}


public class ConfigItem : ConfigItemBase
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Value
    {
        get { return value; }
        set { this.value = value; }
    }
    private string value;

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Description
    {
        get { return description; }
        set { description = value; }
    }
    private string description;
}

[XmlInclude(typeof(ConfigItem)), XmlInclude(typeof(ConfigurationClass))]
public class ConfigItemBase
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Description
    {
        get { return description; }
        set { description = value; }
    }
    private string description;
}
```

and then in Main:

```
ConfigFile MyConfig = new ConfigFile()
{
    Version = new ConfigVersion { Major = 0, Minor = 0 },
    Configuration = new ConfigurationClass
    {
        new ConfigItem() { Description = "My first config item." },
        new ConfigItem() { Description = "My second config item.", Value = "Second Value" },
    }
};

serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, MyConfig);
```

with this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ConfigFile xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Version Major="0" Minor="0" VersionString="Major_0_Minor_0" />
  <Configuration>
    <ConfigItemBase xsi:type="ConfigItem" Description="My first config item." />
    <ConfigItemBase xsi:type="ConfigItem" Description="My second config item." Value="Second Value" />
  </Configuration>
</ConfigFile>
```

Apart for the fact that this did not produce the desired result, since I am using a List to hold the `ConfigItem`, I ran into the problem that I needed add the different data types to the List-class `ConfigurationClass`, which I tried to resolve using `ConfigItemBase`. I suspect, that I will need to use `XmlReader` or `XmlDocument` to achieve what I want...

I am not sure, that what I am proposing is possible, but if so, I hope somebody could point me in the right direction to "jump start" this endeavour. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why the intermediate object?  Just load your XML into an XmlDocument, and query with XPath using SelectSingleNode().  Update it with regular DOM methods.  Skip all the serialization noise.

Comment: @WilliamWalseth Thanks for the comment. Like I said, I am completely new to XML and this is my first attempt. I will take a look at XmlDocument and XPath as you proposed.

Comment: The class names and the tag names do not need to be the same.  When they are not the same you need to add the tag name to the directive [XmlElement("ConfigItem")].  You xml is not easy to parse because you have nestt tags names that are the same.  Maybe use Configuration1, Configuration2, configuration3 to indicate the different levels of configuration tags.

Comment: This twice about using #'s in element names as it really makes it harder to do XSL / XPath queries, since you can't do "//Configuration/ConfigurationItem".